# how to fire menu item click event in ATL OR WTL?

Tags: atl, wtl

Currently i am using the ON_WM_SELECT messgae 
but it will fire on mouse hover over the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the ON_WM_SELECT i used the  COMMAND_RANGE_HANDLER(0, 10000, OnClickCopyItem)
to get the click event for the each menu item

COMMAND_RANGE_HANDLER( idFirst, idLast, func )